# Handling uploads in Android tab using appium

Tags: selenium, appium

I am working on webapp testing using appium and Selenium. I am using Android tab.

I have a scenario handling file uploads in tab. How can we upload a file
in tab?

Comment: have you found solution? i have finding solution for same issue.

Answer (score -2):

In android you need to write some adb command to get the file path in device storage and then pass the path to sendkey.

ADB Commands :

```
adb device - it will give list of device
adb -s <device_id> shell - this will access your android device from command line
cd <file_path_folder>/ - go to the location where you place file in your mobile device
pwd - this will give your file path
```

Get the file from your deivce and use it.